# CKEditor assets cached using shimmed package.json with grunt-browserify

Tags: javascript, caching, browserify, package.json, grunt-browserify

I am shimming CKEdtior to use within my CommonJS modular javascript package.
The issue that I'm having is that the CKEditor assets are being cached somewhere along the line.  I think it's browserify, but I'm not entirely sure.

A cached asset is as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.68.8/cart-admin/ckeditor_4.5.6/config.js?t=FB9E"></script>
```

*This asset is not manually put on the page, it's generated by CKEditor when the JS module runs it's course.*

As is seen above, the query string caches the asset.  However, if I update config.js the asset is still cached and the old version is served.  Even if I re-build my javascript module, the query string cache stays the same and I'm stuck with old assets.

Is there a way to break it?  Or am I going about this incorrectly?

**package.json**

```
"browser": {
  "ckeditor": "./ckeditor_4.5.6/ckeditor.js",
  "ckjquery": "./ckeditor_4.5.6/adapters/jquery.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "ckeditor": "ckeditor",
  "ckjquery": "ckjquery"
}
```

**JS module**

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'ckeditor_4.5.6/';
require('ckeditor');
require('ckjquery');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[Force CKEDITOR to refresh config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940452/force-ckeditor-to-refresh-config)

I changed the requires as such:

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'ckeditor_4.5.6/';
require('ckeditor');
require('ckjquery');
CKEDITOR.timestamp='';
```

`CKEDITOR.timestamp='';` was the key.  Now the `?t=` caching string is no longer appended the asset urls.

Not sure if this is "correct", but it ensures I'm using the most up-to-date files.  perhaps in production I'll add a versioned query string...