# CKEditor Plugins being cached in disk after removal. How can I force the browser to re-scan, or remove that cache?

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu, caching, ckeditor

I'm not sure what the root issue is (Chrome, CKEditor, PHP, Ubuntu, etc.), but this is essentially what's happening:

1. Using Composer to update CKEditor, I change the version and do an update
2. I see that the new version doesn't include a specific plugin (like, Autogrow)
3. After pushing the changes of the composer.json from my local env to production using Git, I update the prod server
4. All looks fine, except for the plugins that didn't exist inside of CKEditor's vendor folder are being loaded "from disk cache"

I can run Chrome in incognito and verify that the plugins that are supposed to be missing are indeed missing. I can't, however, do a cache refresh in Chrome and have the disk cache remove those directories that no longer exist.

Interestingly, Chrome on Android doesn't have this problem, which is how I noticed something was wrong when CKEditor wasn't loading on my phone (missing plugin).

Attempted Solutions:

- Remove CKEditor from composer entirely. Push/pull updates. Re-add CKEditor, still seeing those plugins cached in disk
- Update the ckeditor.js file to be versioned (i.e, ckeditor.js?v=1.02)
- Ran `composer clearcache`
- Tried PHP's `clearstatcache()`

I'm trying to find a solution that I can do from the developer's end, not as an end user.

I'm attaching a screenshot of the js file being cached in disk.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

EDIT:
This is on:

- Ubuntu Server 18.04
- PHP 7.2
- CKEditor 4.8 through 4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this issue has been raised previously:

[Force CKEDITOR to refresh config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940452/force-ckeditor-to-refresh-config)

Credit goes to: @giammin

He wrote:

> ```
> CKEDITOR.timestamp='ABCD';
> ```
>
> **just after you link ckeditor.js** or anyhow before ckeditor loads all its files
>
> this is the variable CKEDITOR uses to add timestamp to all .js .css
>   files it loads dynamically.
>
> So every time I change those files I update that variable and browsers
>   will reload them.

This worked for me. I can see some files still using an older timestamp, but for the purpose of this question, this solved. Again, credit to @giammin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chrome press Shift + F5.. it will clear the cache

Comment: Thank you. But this doesn't clear the cache from disk that I shared as a screenshot. I'm also not looking at how the end user can fix it. I'm looking for how I can force an update that, in essence, forces a re-scan of the vendor directory