# ckeditor required files does not load

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use the ckeditor4 in my project. I have a page (page1) that the ckeditor is loaded its. this  page is loaded in modal components (materialize). when i click to a button on source page (page2), page1 is loaded in modal (loaded in php and return data to client) and ckeditor working without problem. then i closed page1 (modal) and i click to button again on source page for loading page1 (in modal). but this time, ckeditor not working. i check this problem. in first time, load all of ckeditor files, but in second time, just load ckeditor.js .

[image]

load files in first time :

[image]

and second time, just ckediror.js load : 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for this problem. i used `replace` method for generate ckeditor in load page event:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'name_of_textarea' );
```