# Change CKEditor config does not reflect in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I need to support **RTL** text and **LTR** text with **[ckeditor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor)**.

first of all, with the following command I install ng2-ckeditor

```
npm i ng2-ckeditor
```

Then

```
  public responsibilities = 'Angular CkEditor';
  public editorConfig = {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let removeButtons: string = "exportPdf,Source,Templates,Save,NewPage,Print,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Form,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton"
    this.editorConfig = {
      allowedContent: true,
      contentsLangDirection: "ltr",
      forcePasteAsPlainText: true,
      removePlugins: "easyimage, cloudservices, exportpdf,dialog,tableselection,scayt",
      extraPlugins: `${'divarea'}`,
      removeButtons: removeButtons,
      baseFloatZIndex: 9999999999,
      timestamp: +new Date,
      language: 'en'
    }
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
<ckeditor required class="editor form-control input-sm w-100" [(ngModel)]="responsibilities" name="responsibilities"
  id="insert-editor" [config]="editorConfig" [readonly]="false" debounce="500">
</ckeditor>
<br />
<button type="button" (click)="refreshConfig('rtl')">
  Refresh CKEditor Config - (RTL)
</button>

<button type="button" (click)="refreshConfig('ltr')">
  Refresh CKEditor Config - (LTR)
</button>
```

**NOTE**: based on [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940452/force-ckeditor-to-refresh-config) I used `timestamp`, which does not work

Code to change config:

```
  refreshConfig(type: "rtl" | "ltr" = "ltr") {
    type == "rtl" ? this.rtlConfig() : this.ltrConfig();
  }

  private rtlConfig() {
    this.editorConfig = {
      ...this.editorConfig,
      language: 'fa',
      contentsLangDirection: "rtl",
      timestamp: +new Date
    }
  }

  private ltrConfig() {
    this.editorConfig = {
      ...this.editorConfig,
      language: 'en',
      contentsLangDirection: "ltr",
      timestamp: +new Date
    }
  }
```

**NOTE**

if set `language` to `fa` and `contentsLangDirection` to `rtl` in `ngOnInit` hook
or set `language` to `en` and `contentsLangDirection` to `ltr`
it works.

**[Stackblitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ydbljr?file=src/index.html)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the library does not reload the editor when the config changes, your config won't apply.

As far as I know, it is not possible to apply new configs after the editor was initialized.

There are different ways to force rerendering the editor. Because you are dealing with a library, I suggest to rerender the component by *ngIf directive or by using the ng-template way.

To rerender with *ngIf directive, just define a boolean variable which you enable before you make change to the config and enable afterwards.
Because angular dom does not recognize the enable/disable in the same method, you need to force change detection when you activate the component.

Here is my example:

```
public configChanging = false;
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  private rtlConfig() {
    this.configChanging = true;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

    this.editorConfig = {
      ...this.editorConfig,
      language: 'fa',
      contentsLangDirection: 'rtl',
      timestamp: +new Date(),
    };

    this.configChanging = false;
  }
```

And in your template you add the *ngIf directive

```
<ckeditor *ngIf="!configChanging"></ckeditor>
```

Here is a [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpmrmb?file=src/app/app.component.html) of your Stackblitz with my solution